# Adwords editor using Play on Linux

Tags: playonlinux

I am very new to Ubuntu and I would really love to make it work for me. I have tried to install adwords editor on my Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS and with the info found online I have followed the Play on Linux solution. After trying to install I receive this message:

```
Error in POL_Shortcut
Binary not found: Program Files/Google/Google AdWords Editor/adwords_editor.exe
Have you installed the program to the default location?
```

Could anyone offer a step by step guide to successfully install and run adwords editor on my system please?

Thank you

Daniel

Comment: As the error says "Have you installed the program to the default location?!, where did you install it too? Look in your file browser for `/home/.wine/C:/Program Files/Google/Google AdWords Editor/adwords_editor.exe`is it there? can you run it from here?

Comment: Also, what adwords version are you trying to install? wine hq says it won't work and gives it a garbage rating on Ubuntu https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?bShowAll=true&bIsQueue=false&bIsRejected=false&sClass=version&sTitle=&sReturnTo=&iId=32146

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, I have no idea on how to check that folder and whether adwords is in there. Also, the version of adwords is displayed in play on linux. There are two different versions there and I have tried both of them, obtaining the same result. thank you, Daniel

Comment: To find the .exe open your files and press CTRL+H to show hidden ones, then follow this path to find it `/home/.wine/C:/Program Files/Google/Google AdWords Editor/adwords_editor.exe` it may be a bit diffrent but once you get to `C:/` it is the same as Windows. s

Comment: Hi, that's great I have done that and I can see that the folder doesn't exist! What am I supposed to do please? Daniel

Comment: Open a terminal and run `locate adwords_editor.exe` this will give you the path to the file, browse to it and open with `wine` or `play on linux`

Comment: That's great! Although now when I open the file I get this error message: Unable to connect to the internet. If you use a firewall, please whitelist GoogleUpdate.exe. :-(

Comment: I am sorry say it won't work :( As I said it has a garbage rating on wine.hq, this has been asked before but there is no fix, `wine` is not a guaranteed working solution, it is in constant flux, based on what are currently popular applications. You can wait to see if someone can give a fix, but it is not likely.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can try installing Windows 7 on VirtualBox, and then run adwords editor that way. A huge hassle, considering that you would have to pay for a legal copy of windows, and install it, and configure it, just to get adwords editor to work.